# Lots of memory leaks

Tags: c++, sfml

I have installed SFML, put my project properties like stated on the website of SFML, and copy pasted their default code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;
}
```

But this is giving me loads of memory leaks. Here is an image of some of the memory leaks:
[image]

Why am I getting all these memory leaks?

Comment: You can rest easy and just ignore them. Considering your code example they seem to be static objects SFML needs to have around.

Comment: But how do I test my code then for memory leaks? I am a beginner with C++ so maybe I will make memory leaks by accident.

Comment: if you stay away from raw owning pointers and naked `new` it is actually not that easy to leak memory. Rule of thumb: zero `new`s need zero `delete`s.

Comment: Hi, try with all the includes and `int main() { _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }`. You will probably get memory leaks due to static objects. Check the highest allocation number and you can later consider only the memory leaks *after* that number.

Answer (score 0):

`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` cannot look into the future and know what will be destroyed after you call it.

Hence, this will report leaks:

```
int main() {
    int y = 0;
    int* x = new int;
     _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    delete x;
}
```

And this will not:

```
int main() {
    {
        int y = 0;
        int* x = new int;
        delete x;
    }
     _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Comment: I have placed an open bracket before the creation of the window and an close bracket before the crtdump but it is still reporting all the memory leaks

Comment: @JelleVos really *all* the leaks? Or is it leasks of static objects that only get destroyed when `main` returns?

Comment: there are so many leaks that I cannot really see if there are a few gone. But I think they are still all there.